# Mongodb Aggregation group by on more than one field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am applying aggregation on a collection and I would like to group by more than one field. All the calculations are same in the pipeline. I would like to see the results grouped by different fields.

possible values for the fields that I am using:

```
ageCategory -> 10, 20, 30 40
sex -> Male, Female
type -> A,B,C,D,E
stage -> I, II, III, IV
```

This is how I am doing this now:

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection("collection").aggregate([
            { $match: //match conditions },
            { $project: { 
                   ageCategory: 1,
                   sex: 1,
                   type: 1,
                   stage: 1,
                   //other fileds
                } 
            },
            { $match: //match conditions } ,
            { $project: { 
                   ageCategory: 1,
                   sex: 1,
                   type: 1,
                   stage: 1,
                   //other fileds
                } 
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "result",
                    age10: { $sum: { $cond:[//condition for ageCategory 10,1,0]  } },
                    age20: { $sum: { //condition for ageCategory 10  } },
                    //other age categories
                    male: { $sum: { //condition for male  } },
                    female: { $sum: { //condition for female  } },                        
                    typeA: { $sum: { //condition for type A } },
                    typeB: { $sum: { //condition for type B  } },
                    //other conditions
                }
           }
        ]).toArray(function (err, result) {
            //final computations
        });
```

Simplified representation of the data and result expected: (there are some calculations that happen in the match and project statements, which are ignored for simplicity)

```
[{
    ageCategory: "10",
    sex: "Male",
    type: "A",
    stage: "I",
    sub:[
        {}
    ],
    //other sub documents that are used in the pipeline
},
{
    ageCategory: "20",
    sex: "Male",
    type: "B",
    stage: "I",
    sub:[
        {}
    ],
    //other sub documents that are used in the pipeline
}]
```

Expected Result:

```
{
    age10:1, //count of sub with ageCategory as 10
    age20:1,
    //other count by age. It is okay to ignore the ones with zero count.
    male: 2,
    typeA: 1,
    typeB: 1,
    stageI: 2
}
```

I am checking all the conditions in the group by. I am not sure if this is a best way to do it. One options is to run this aggregation multiple times with group by applied on individual field, but that is causing performance issues and also repetition of the same query.

I cannot use mapReduce because of performance reasons.

Is this the best way to do this? or any alternative approaches?

Comment: So what's your precise question?

Comment: updated my question. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a simple example of input data and the expected output?

Comment: @cbartosiak Added sample data to the question.

Comment: Could you explain why `stageI` equals `"I"`?

Comment: And why does `typeB` equal to `2`?

Comment: @cbartosiak so sorry, I need more coffee. Corrected the expected result. typeA is 1, typeB is 1, stageI is 2

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided expected result it's safe to say you want to get **totals**. In such case you should group documents by **null** and not `"result"`, because we don't know what it might mean for Mongo in future.

I think the problem with your question is that you use "group by" term, but in fact you mean computing fields holding the values of some accumulator expressions.

Well, the way you have done this seems to be OK for me (apart from the **null**/`"result"` thing).

Comment: you are exactly right about groupby. But what is the advantage of using $project with the condition vs using the same condition in the in the $group? with my existing code I am getting the expected resulted.

Comment: I have edited my answer to focus on the key points and to not mislead people. If you don't have to don't use `$project` before `$group`, because it might be slower than inlines you have.